# Android Studio Requires Catching Throwable when using orElseThrow method

Tags: java, android, option-type

I am writing an application in Android Studio. My current version is 3.1.0. I am trying to use the orElseThrow method from the Optional class. I checked the settings for Android Studio, and it requires an API level of at least 24 to use Optional. I'm currently using API level 25, and my JDK is 1.8.0_151.

I have created a new Android Studio project using an Empty Activity. I have created a class called TestClass that contains the following code:

```
package com.examples.myapplication;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public final class TestClass {

    private final List<Integer> numbers;

    public TestClass() {
        numbers = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
    }

    public final int doesNumberExist(final int number) {
        return numbers.stream().filter(n -> n == number).findAny().orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
    }
}
```

The problem that I'm having here is that Android Studio gives me a compile-time error on the orElseThrow() call in the doesNumberExist() method.

The error is:

```
Unhandled exception: java.lang.Throwable
```

I've tried running the orElseThrow method in a different IDE, and there is no compile-time error on that line of code, so I believe that the problem lies in Android Studio, but I can't figure out what would be causing the problem. I have tried raising the API level, but I can only go up to 26, and that didn't do anything.

From my understanding of the way that the orElseThrow() method works, the type of exception that you should have to handle is any checked exception that you throw inside the method call. In this example, I've used RuntimeException, so I shouldn't have to handle catching any exceptions.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could update your question with a [minimal, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Great suggestion @Radiodef & a tip: `[mcve]` in a comment auto-expands to [mcve].

Comment: The question seems complete to me, the above code reproduces the problem for me as well .

Comment: i have opened an issue on that : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120871350

Answer (score -1):

```
public final int doesNumberExist(final int number) throws Throwable {
    Optional<int> f = numbers.stream().filter(n -> n == number).findAny();
    return  f.orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
}
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) work, a good answer should always explain what the problem is and how it gets solved.